# Diagonalizing the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}2&-1&0&0\\-1&2&-1&0\\0&-1&2&-1\\0&0&-1&2\end{bmatrix}$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Evaluate the eigenvalues of the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}2&-1&0&0\\-1&2&-1&0\\0&-1&2&-1\\0&0&-1&2\end{bmatrix}$

In my reference it is given that eigenvalues of the matrix all have the form $2-2\cos\theta=4\sin^2(\theta/2)$. The $n$ different angles $\theta$ are equally spaced, $\theta=\dfrac{\pi}{2n+1},\dfrac{3\pi}{3n+1},\cdots\cdots,\dfrac{(2n-1)\pi}{2n+1}$.

I have got no idea where does these $\theta$ comes in for the eigenvalues of the given matrix ?

Exact description in the reference:

[image: pic]

**Reference:** Page 368, Chapter 7-The Singular Value Decomposition (SVD), [Introduction to Linear Algebra, Gilbert Strang, 5th Edition](http://math.mit.edu/%7Egs/linearalgebra/)

Comment: The entry in the lower right corner should also be $2,$  same as the rest of the main diagonal

Comment: My online calculator says $\lambda^4-7\lambda^3+15\lambda^2-10\lambda+1$ with root 1 and three other reals. The typo Will Jagy mentioned gives your polynomial.

Comment: @MariusS.L. the 4,4 entry is wrong

Comment: @Will Jagy I saw the Cartan matrix, but nobody said it is one,

Comment: @MariusS.L.  the characteristic polynomial given in the question  does not match his matrix. It does match the matrix with 4,4 position changed to $2$ People leave wrong or inconsistent questions and run away.... I have no explanation for the $n$ and the $\theta,$  from the answer below I'm guessing the pattern is to be extended to an $n$ by $n$ Toeplitz matrix, eigenvalues of such things are known. Not by me, but by some people

Comment: @MariusS.L. ,Will Jagy the (4,4)th element is given in the reference as 1 not 2, don't know if its a typo or not.

Comment: @WillJagy I have edited OP to include the original description in the reference, please do check.

Comment: @WillJagy Yes, this is a well known sequence of matrices (after the correction). I know it primarily as the Cartan matrix of the root system of type $A_n$.

Comment: Just because the cosines appear, I believe that Chebyshev polynomials show up in a descriptioin the characteristic polynomial of the correct matrix also (with $1$ at bottom right). After all, expanding the characteristic polynomial along the last row still has the $U_n$s as cofactors (just with different coefficienst). I don't have the time to look at it now. May be in the weekend? I am leaving my answer  for now as the description of Chebyshev polynomials as determinants of Töplitz matrices may come in handy. G'night.

Answer (score 3):

This is one of my favorite collections of matrices.

Let's define

$$
U_n(x)=\det
\left(\begin{array}{cccccc}
2x&-1&0&0&\cdots&0\\
-1&2x&-1&0&\cdots&0\\
0&-1&2x&-1&\cdots&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\ddots&\cdots&\vdots\\
0&\cdots&\cdots&-1&2x&-1\\
0&\cdots&\cdots&0&-1&2x
\end{array}\right),
$$
where $n$ is the number of rows.
Expanding this along the bottom row gives the recurrency relation of depth two
$$
U_{n+1}(x)=2x U_n(x)-U_{n-1}(x).
$$
And we also have
$$
U_0(x)=1,\qquad U_1(2x).
$$
This means that the polynomials $U_n(x)$ are exactly [the Chebyshev polynomials of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials).

Meaning that
$$
U_n(\cos\theta)=\frac{\sin((n+1)\theta)}{\sin\theta}.
$$
The proof for this is standard (see loc. linked).
For example the familiar trig formula
$$
\sin 2x=2\cos x\sin x
$$
is equivalent to $U_1(\cos x)=2\cos x$.

Anyway, we know that $\sin((n+1)\theta)=0$ when $\theta=\theta_k=k\pi/(n+1)$ for $k=1,2,\ldots,n$, but
$\sin \theta_k\neq0$ for all $k$. Therefore
$$
U_n(\cos \theta_k)=0
$$
for all $k=1,2,\ldots, n$. Cosine is a decreasing function in the interval $[0,\pi]$, so the numbers $x_k=\cos\theta_k$, $k=1,2,\ldots,n$, are exactly the zeros of $U_n(x)$.

---

If $\chi_n(T)=\det(M_n-TI_n)$ is the characteristic polynomial of your matrix $M_n$ (the version with $n$ rows), then
$$
\chi_n(2-2x)=U_n(x).
$$
It follows that the eigenvalues of $M_n$ are the numbers
$$
\lambda_k=2-2x_k=2-2\cos\frac{k\pi}{n+1},\quad k=1,2,\ldots,n
$$

Comment: My first attempt at searching this came out empty. Hence I decided to post an answer. Will delete, if this turns out a duplicate (as is still likely IMO).

Comment: If (4,4)th term is 2 not 1, then is it not $-(\Delta x)^2A$, where $A$ is the difference operator corresponds to the second derivative ? does that somehow help finding the eigenvalues ?

Comment: Jyrki, good answer. It would seem the OP, and possibly the Strang book, are mixing together two problems, one with Toeplitz. In question formula(s) (4) there are a symmetric matrix of integers and its inverse. The inverse, which I checked, really does have a 1 insted of 2 in the lower right hand corner, position 4,4. Perhaps this is from a solutions manual or unauthorized answer book. If you look at the edit history, the question had, at first, a characteristic polynomial. In effect, we do not really know the "context" as what appears is inconsistent

Comment: I see @WillJagy. I just saw the Cartan matrix, and jumped the gun.

Comment: It's a nice topic; there is a video of Strang lecturing on precisely what you address... here is a short one, there is a full lecture somewhere oline  by a much younger Strang https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1DvlyNjfuzM